# jqPlot charts on page load

Tags: html, load, jqplot

I have a form where I select the number of items. Upon clicking submit, it should take me to a new page where it would display the item selected and depending on the number of items selected, it would create those many jqPlots, one for each item.

Any suggestions on how do I go about doing this?

Thanks, 
S.

Comment: Are you submitting the form with POST?

Comment: They are basically JSF pages. So, upon clicking the submit button, I have an action that would redirect me to the desired page.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give any specifics without more detail about the items, but basically you would pass a JSON structure to your view with the items to be plotted. Then you would loop through the JSON structure, creating DIV tag for each item to be plotted and appending the DIV tags to the body.

The Javascript part would look something like this:

```
$.each(items, function(index, value) {
  $myPlot = $("<div>");

  $myPlot.attr("id", "item"+index);

  $.jqplot($myPlot.attr("id"), ...);

  $("body").append($myPlot);

});
```

Comment: Thanks, that gave me an idea. I am trying to something similar. I have JSF for the front end and Groovy classes as the backing beans. I would try to look at these function. 
I am a newbbie to all these technologies. Do you have any sample/reference that I could read up to get more insights on the same? Like to how to convert the data to JSON and how do I go about calling this javascript function from the JSF page(given that I am having a separate JS file).

Comment: @reg_frenzy Unfortunately, I am not familiar with either. I would recommend opening a new question for implementation specific questions regarding those frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very general, but answering (specifically and only) the question of loading multiple charts:

You need a unique HTML div id for each chart; consider using an RFC 4122 UUID (generate as needed) for each chart/div rather than a sequential index for each.  Use something that looks like this as a placeholder div for each:

```
<div class="chartdiv" id="chartdiv-${UID}">
  <a rel="api" type="application/json" href="${JSON_URL}" style="display:none">Data</a>
</div>
```

This embeds the JSON URL for each div inside it, in a hidden hyperlink that can be discovered by JavaScript iterating over your multi-chart HTML page.

The matter of the UUID is inconsequential -- it just seems the most robust way to guarantee a unique HTML id addressable by JavaScript for each chart.

Subsequently, you should have JavaScript that looks something like:

```
jq('document').ready(function(){
    jq('.chartdiv').each(function(index) {
        var div = jq(this);
        var json_url = jq('a[type="application/json"]', div).attr('href');
        var divid = div.attr('id'); 
        jq.ajax({
            url: json_url,
            success: function(responseText) { /*callback*/
                // TODO: responseText is JSON, use it, normalize it, whatever!
                var chartdata = responseText;
                jq.jqplot(divid, chartdata.seriesdata, chartdata.options);
            }   
        }); 
    }); 

});
```